# Need help aligning tables ...HTML

Tags: html, css

This should be an easy one. Just so you know, I normally write java logic, so styling is not my cup of tea, but got to do it. Anyway I just got this:

[image]

Im trying to get the tables to be side by side instead of on top of each other like this:
[image]

Here's the HTML... thanks for your help.... Let me know if you need to see more code

```html
<tr><tr><tr><tr><tr><tr>
    <table class="link_table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>

    <table class="link_table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <table class="link_table" style="display:inline">
```

Comment: you can also put space with  : `display:'inline-block;margin-left:30px;'`

Answer (score 2):

People are going to tell you not to use tables, and they'd be right. That said, you just need these two items in table cells in the same row:

```html
<table class="link_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I do it this way, it puts the text all in the same cell

Comment: Sounds like you've got styling on link_table to handle the borders and styling. You'll have to change that styling to work on the td <td class="link_table"> or something along those lines.

Comment: Yeah it does, I try not to mess with the CSS because it's used in so many places.  Have to alter the JSP...thanks

Comment: @suknic - You don't need to be adding all the `<!-- language: whatever -->` tags to the code you edit; the system can determine the language automatically for most languages (see these two meta posts: [\[1\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019), [\[2\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)).

Comment: @eykanal I added the language tags to the code because it did not determine the correct or any language. And unformatted code is more trouble to read. I am sorry that I did it on so many posts, but I got carried away when I saw that none of the posts here where formatted correctly. I appologize.

Answer (score 1):

Add them to cells (td), Not seperate tables. :)

```
<table class="link_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to use tables for layout, but if you absolutely have to do it then you could use the following css on your table element in this case:

```
style="display: inline;"
```

Comment: This worked....how would i put space in-between them, they are rubbing next to each other.  Thanks alot

Comment: You'd want to add some margins, something like style="display: inline;margin: 0 10px;"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table class="link_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="show.addEdit_hotpart?hotPartId=0">ADD HOT PART</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In my situation, this just put the text in the same cell

Comment: Probably it has something to do with the link_table class you applied in the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

The table element works as a block-level element. A block-level element creates a linebreak. To modify the behavior use the CSS property "`display`":

```
.link_table{ float:left; }
```

That's not a pretty solution, but it works. Everything else involves more reading about HTML and CSS.

Cheers